# Import Binary Modules in Powershell 3 with dll references located in different folder

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-module, pssnapin

I am converting a powershell snapin(which was working really fine) to a powershell module.

I have added the output dll to a folder with the same name as the dll and added the Module path to the `$env:PSModulePath`

The import seems to fail because the Snapin had some references to some other dll's(located in the `bin\` folder)

I also don't want to copy all referenced dll's into the modules folder because they are already in the bin folder.

Is there a way to indicate the folder in which the referenced dll's are located in powershell? Maybe to indicate the folder like it is done for individual dll's:

`[reflection.assembly]::loadfrom(full name of referenced dll)`

Comment: May I ask why you don't want to copy the referenced dlls to the module's folder? I believe that is a fairly standard practice.

Comment: @blachniet: The reason is because I already have the dll's compiled into the **bin\** folder. I only want to reference them from the modules folder. Consider the case when I have 20 modules and then I will have all the dll's copied in each module separately...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to load the referenced dlls from another folder. If you just want one dll in the destination folder, you could use [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) ([available via NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ilmerge/)) to merge the primary output assembly and referenced assemblies into one dll.